# how do I call a method? in Java

Tags: java, methods, call

```
public static void main(String args [])
{
    double dimes;
    double quaters;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter number of Dimes:");
    dimes = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter Number of Quaters:");
    quaters = input.nextDouble();

    double dollars= dollar_amount(dimes,quaters);
    System.out.println("Dollar Amount total: $" + dollars);

    public static double dollar_amount(dimes,quaters);
    dollars= dollar_amount(dimes,quaters);
    System.out.println("Total dollar amount: $" + dollars);
}

double dollar_amount(double dimes, double quaters);
{
    dollars = (0.10 * dimes)+(0.25 * quaters);
}

return dollars;

}
}
}
```

I have a question on how to call a method. I had follow the hints that I was given, but somehow I don't quite get on calling a method.

hint:

1. input dimes
2. input quarters
3. **call the method dollar_amout(dimes, quarters)**
4. dollars = dollar_amount(dimes, quarters)
5. end main
6. double dollar_amount(dimes, quarters)
7. dollars = 0.10 x dimes + 0.25 x quarters
8. return dollars
9. end method

Comment: In the code provided you are already calling a method. Are you having difficulties identifying what line this is happening on?

Comment: the hint tells me **call the method dollar_amout(dimes, quarters)** I believe i put that in the wrong place.

Comment: You still haven't stated your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method body is wrong

```
Double dollar_amount(double dimes, double quaters);
{
  Double dollars = (0.10 * dimes)+(0.25 * quaters);
  return dollars;   
}
```

And your calling it right place. No problem with that

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is trying to set the value of a variable using a method. You must define the method `dollar_amount(dimes,quaters)`properly before you can call it.

Paste this code over your current code, into your main class.

```
public static void main(String args []){
   double dimes;
   double quaters;

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter number of Dimes:");
   dimes = input.nextDouble();

   System.out.print("Enter Number of Quaters:");
   quaters = input.nextDouble();

   double dollars= dollar_amount(dimes,quaters);
   System.out.println("Dollar Amount total: $" + dollars);

}

public static double dollar_amount(dimes,quaters){
   dollars = (0.10 * dimes)+(0.25 * quaters);
   return dollars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes, try like this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double dimes;
    double quaters;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter number of Dimes:");
    dimes = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter Number of Quaters:");
    quaters = input.nextDouble();

    double dollars = dollar_amount(dimes, quaters);
    System.out.println("Dollar Amount total: $" + dollars);

    dollars = dollar_amount(dimes, quaters);
    System.out.println("Total dollar amount: $" + dollars);
}

public static double dollar_amount(double dimes, double quaters) {
    double dollars = (0.10 * dimes) + (0.25 * quaters);
    return dollars;
}
```

Comment: I made the mistake of putting the method before ending the main. This really helped me see what I did wrong. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Charlos A common way of saying thanks here on StackOverflow and other StackExchange sites is voting an answer/question up by clicking the arrow up above the number to the left (if the answer/question was useful) or accepting an answer by ticking the check mark below the number to the left. You also get reputation for accepting answers.